# Margin 0 Auto Not Working On Div CSS

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm currently trying to center center a div with a form inside of it, however it doesn't seem to want to center with `margin: 0 auto;`. I have made sure to add `display: block;` to the div but it still won't work!

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="card form-card">
        <form class="formPassword" action="" method="post">
            <ul style="list-style-type:none;padding-top:50px;margin-left:-40px;">
                <li>
                    <input class="formInputPassword" type="password" name="current_password" placeholder="Current Password"><br><br><br><br>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input class="formInputPassword" type="password" name="password" placeholder="New Password"><br><br>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input class="formInputPassword" type="password" name="password_again" placeholder="Repeat Password"><br><br>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save"><br><br>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
        .liInline{
            display:inline-block;
            list-style-type:none;
        }
        div.card{
            display:block;
        }
        .card{
            display:block;
            padding: 20px 25px 30px;
            margin: 0 auto 25px;
            width: auto;
        }
        .formInputPassword{
            width:370px;
            height:38px;
            font-size:1.6em;
            text-align:center;
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: is it inheriting from any of the parent divs?

Comment: @MatthewRath pardon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Give `text-align: center;` to `div.card` will make your form center..

```
div.card{
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ds4d6c7m/)**

**Solution 2:**

`margin:0 auto;` works when it have parent div and fixed width.
Like here i give form fixed width and margin:0 auto. will make form horizontal center.

```
.formPassword{
      margin:0 auto;
       width:250px;
  }
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ds4d6c7m/1/)**

**Solution 3:**

And if you don't want to give fixed width, then use `display:table`

```
.formPassword {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ds4d6c7m/3/)**

Comment: And just FYI, a `div` is already a block element.  There is absolutely no need to add `display: block;`. Also...  qualifying the `.card` selector (div.card) is very bad practice and highly unrecommended. Never do that.

Answer (score 0):

if you want form in center you can text-align center in card class
like eg.

```
.card{
            display:block;
            padding: 20px 25px 30px;
            margin: 0px auto;

            background:gray;
            text-align:center;
        }
```

hope will help you.